# laravel how to specifiy the input columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a form in html that has an input with name `restaurantName`, but my column in the database is `name`. I am not able to use this in the controller

```
Restaurant::create(Input::only('restaurantName'));
```

Because there is no column with `restaurantName` so my question is how to tell laravel that `restaurantName` is maped to `name` ?

many thanks

#### Edit

the html form has these fields:

```
restaurantName
website
username
password
mobileNumber
firstName
lastName
```

The database has two tables which are `Admin` and `Restaurant`, each restaurant has one admin and the admin is one for each restaurant, so it is one to one relationship

when I submit the form I do the following:

```
$input = Input::all();
 $admin = Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));

                $data = ['name' , Input::get('restaurantName'), 'website' => Input::get('website')];
                $restaurant = new Restaurant($data);
                $admin->restaurant()->save($restaurant);
```

the `admin` row is inserted to the database so the problem starts with the `$data` line code.

the exception is:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should never just blindly pass user input to models, and secondly, this particular problem has absolutely nothing to do with laravel.

Your problem can be solved with basic PHP. Simply, create your own array of input.

```
$data = [
    'field'    => Input::get('field'),
    'name'     => Input::get('restaurantName')
];
```

There seems to be a grave misconception that Laravel is its own independant system, it is not. It is literally a collection of PHP code, it doesn't do anything that can't be done with PHP and it doesn't prevent you from doing anything you can normally do with PHP.

Comment: could you explain your code please? what should I do with $data variable? how can I pass it to the Input function? what is the `field` you stated?

Comment: You don't pass anything to `Input`. `Input` is a library that simply facilitates the retrieval of user input. The `$data` variable would be passed to the create function, and 'field' was simply a random field name to show you how it'd work. I don't mean to be rude, but this is all fundamental PHP, which it may be worth looking into before something as complex as this.

Comment: I will edit the question to show you the result of your code:

Comment: I edited the question with the exception that I got, could you check please? the `save` function is not exist

Comment: Firstly, your $data array is wrong, it should be `'name' => Input..` not `'name', Input..`. I also literally just said, don't blindly pass arrays into create, you should validate first. The error you're getting has absolutely zero to do with the array, it's because you're trying to save a relationship on what appears to be a non-relationship.

Comment: Dear, I know that I have to validate first, but I just give you the related code otherwise I would give you a whole code, I am trying to make the give you just the relevant code to simplify it to you. and I do have the relationship correct in my models. it is one to one relationship. the restaurant table has `adminID` field, but the `admin` table doesn't have `resturantID` field, should I add that field please?

Comment: Don't post new questions that are simply a continuation of the first question. You're inserting the model incorrectly, your relationship is setup so that it's `restaurant->admin()->save()`

Comment: when I correct as you said `restaurant()->admin()->save` I got exception: `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in C:\xampp2\htdocs\ParkingProject\app\controllers\RestaurantsController.php on line 44 and defined` line 44 is the `restaurant->admin->save()`

Comment: Yes, your relationships are the wrong way around, you can't insert a restaurant as an admin. I don't mean to be rude, but your problem is that you haven't read the docs, either of laravel or PHP, please do so, it'll help, trust me.

Comment: I am trying to fix that though I already read the relsationshipt documentation

Comment: it is working now, many thanks, but please don't use hard words next time because I already read the documentation or releationship in laravel.