# php laravel how to insert a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have two tables which are:

**Admin:**

```
ID | username | password | mobileNumber | firstName | lastName
```

**Restaurant:**

```
website | adminID | name
```

I have an html form that has this data

```
restaurantName
website
username
password
mobileNumber
firstName
lastName
```

When I submit that form I want to insert the data to the admin table, then insert the data with the adminID to the restaurant table:

I tried this:

```
$input = Input::all();
$admin = Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));

$data = [
   'name' , 
   Input::get('restaurantName'), 
   'website' => Input::get('website')
];

$restaurant = new Restaurant($data);
$admin->restaurant()->save($restaurant);
```

But I got this exception:

```
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

could you help please?

#### Admin model

```
class Admin  extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

public function restaurant(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant', 'ID');
}
```

#### Restaurant model

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

public function admin(){
    return $this->hasOne('Admin', 'adminID');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel how to specifiy the input columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283510/laravel-how-to-specifiy-the-input-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$restaurant->admin()->associate($admin);
$restaurant->save();
```